# Internationalizaton of HTML Files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internationalization

I am developing a project and uses HTML files (not JSP or any other technology at client side). I use JQuery for scripting. I have tables, columns, and many fields that have "text" on them. How can I internationalize my web page with JQuery? I mean I will load a file _tr.extension and my web page will be Turkish, _swe.extension will be Swedish etc.

Any ideas?

**EDIT1:** For example I will write a code like that:

```
<div>${name}</div>
<div>${surname}</div>
```

and there will be a _tr.properties file like that:

```
name = isim
surname = soyisim
```

and there will be a _swe.properties file like that:

```
name = namn
surname = efternamn
```

And if I change the imported file that texts inside that divs will be at different language per pages.

**EDIT2:** That functionality is enough for me I don't want more I need a speedy and lightweight plug-in (Maybe feeding from JSON can be an additional specialty).

Comment: Localizer plug-in - http://plugins.jquery.com/project/localizer looks like good, I will check it.

Comment: if you ever need more (like proper plural support, variables,..) you might take a look at http://i18next.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localizer plug-in - plugins.jquery.com/project/localizer is simple and works well.

Answer (score 3):

I can strongly recommend [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) as an translating and formatting solution.

To translate you would use the code similar to that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="globalize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cultures/globalize.cultures.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  Globalize.addCultureInfo( "tr", {
    messages: {
      "name" : "isim",
      "surname" : "soyisim"
    }
  });
  // Swedish language code is actually sv
  Globalize.addCultureInfo( "sv", {
    messages: {
      "name" : "namn",
      "surname" : "efternamn"
    }
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    // you need somehow know what language to use
    // but it is out of scope of this answer
    $( "name" ).val( Globalize.localize( "name", "tr" ) );
    $( "surname" ).val( Globalize.localize( "surname", "tr" ) );
  });
</script>
```

To use this script you would need to modify your html as follows:

```
<!-- DIV is just a container, P (paragraph) or SPAN 
     are more suitable for the job. Also this shows
     neutral language texts.
     Be sure to use unique IDs -->
<div><p id="name">name</p></div>
<div><p id="surname">surname</p></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few suggestions.
(i18n == internationalization)

http://plugins.jquery.com/i18n/ 
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-utils/wiki/I18N 
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-i18n-properties/

**EDIT:** for your needs I recommend https://github.com/jquery-i18n-properties/jquery-i18n-properties

Comment: I have edited my question, which one do you suggest according to my needs?

Comment: How can I use  jqueryi18n to achieve translating without programatically setting the value to html like : <div>${name}</div>
<div>${surname}</div>

Answer (score 1):

I second Pawel Dyda's answer to use Jquery Globalize Plugin. We are using similar solution in our project.

Steps below.

1. Download Jquery Globalize Plugin

   https://github.com/jquery/globalize
2. Include **globalize.js** and the JS files for the cultures you need in your HTML file

   e.g., **globalize.culture.tr.js**
3. Add HTML code with IDs

   ```
   <div id="name"></div>
   <div id="surname></div>
   ```
4. Add name and surname to the messages section of the respective language JS files

   Turkish JS File

   ```
    messages : 
   {
   "name": "isim",
   "surname": "soyisim"    
   }
   ```

   Swedish JS file

   ```
    messages :
        {
       "name": "namn"
   "surname": "efternamn"
   }
   ```
5. Set the culture based on selection

   ```
    Globalize.Culture("tr");
   ```
6. Update the strings for the culture using .text function or .html function

   ```
      $("#name").text(Globalize.localize("name",globalize.culture()));
      $("#surname").text(Globalize.localize("surame",globalize.culture()));
   ```

In our project, we are also using JSON string to populate dropdowns based on culture

1. Save the dropdown name and value pairs as a JSON string in the messages section
2. Convert the JSON string to JSON object
3. Loop the JSON object and set the Option Name and Value for the dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery templating API to replace all of your written words with variables which can be defined dynamically.

See more here: http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/

Answer (score 0):

I'd not use JQuery to internationalise the content of your web pages, it's not a good choice of technologies as JavaScript can't be relied on to be active in the browser or client reading your pages.

You'd be better off using a server side language to feed content into HTML templates, or if this isn't possible, creating duplicate pages for each language and marking them up appropriately.

Comment: I want to do that internationalization process at client side cos my application will be separated from main server side as possible as. I will communicate with REST services. Duplicate page idea may be bad for adding new language or changing a language to another i.e. I change change the language according to browser's default language as well.

Comment: I still maintain you are considering the wrong technology. JavaScript should be used to enhance web pages, not relied upon to display their content.

Comment: Question is how to use jQuery for internationalization.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [gettext](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/gettext) jQuery plugin. gettext is a standard with language files that have awesome editing tools, which will make the experience a lot easier in the case you have to do deal with a translation service (or even internal people who are not highly technical).

For the URL issue, your web server likely has some capability to help by rewriting the URLs. For example `.htaccess` in Apache. (You may wish to post that as a separate question.)

Answer (score 0):

Index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>javascript - Internationalizaton of HTML Files</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="globalize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="globalize.cultures.js"></script>
<p id="name">name</p>
<p id="surname">surname</p>

  <script>
function myFunction()
 {
 surname=document.getElementById("surname");  //Find the element
 surname.innerHTML=Globalize.localize( "surname", "fr" );    //Change the content
 n=document.getElementById("name");
 n.innerHTML=Globalize.localize("name","fr");
}
 window.onload=function(){
 var language=window.navigator.language; //default language en-US
 surname=document.getElementById("surname");  //Find the element
 surname.innerHTML=Globalize.localize( "surname", language );    //Change the content
 n=document.getElementById("name");
 n.innerHTML=Globalize.localize("name",language);

 };
</script>
 <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

globalize.cultures.js file

```
  Globalize.addCultureInfo( "en-US", {
    messages: {
     "name" : "English Name",
     "surname" : "English Surname"
    }
   });
   // French language code is actually fr

       Globalize.addCultureInfo( "fr", {
       messages: {
     "name" : "French name",
    "surname" : "French Surname"
      }
    });
```